# How to encrypt with openssl_encrypt using AES and salt in place of Base64

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

Currently I am using `openssl_encrypt` to encrypt the data and it return base64 value. I have to use AES encryption with salt.

Can any one tell how to implement AES encryption with salt?

---

Here is the code I use:

```php
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string)
{
    $output = false;

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    if ($action == 'encrypt') {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: You don't "salt" encryption.  Your question is very vague.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

Always use tested libraries for such purposes. Your encryption is vulnerable and completely insecure because you're not using IV correctly.

Consider using [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) library and get rid of what you've done.

Why is what you've done wrong:

- The same IV (initialization vector) is used.
- There is no **salt** in encryption, it's called **Initialization Vector** and it **must** be different every time you encrypt - your IV is always the same
- When encryption is done, you must deliver the encrypted data **and** IV - you are not returning IV with encryption result, only the result.

Currently, you are not doing what I outlined and that's why you should invest your time into using a library that takes care of encryption so you don't roll out your own, insecure implementation. I'm **deliberately not posting the code** required for this encryption to work from fear that someone will use it, instead of library that I linked. Always use libraries made by other people if you have no idea what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs it, and yes you can add salt using openssl_pbkdf2

```
$ciphertext_b64 = "";
$plaintext = "hello alice";
$password = "XhcwO1NNI1Xi43EVAtVPS1vknOGgsgIu16OmUAtzlGoHtaPYWwLqxxAEHcBbocWiaYYtBSlgvkn5rVBu";
$salt = "CK4OGOAtec0zgbNoCK4OGOAtec0zgbNoCK4OGOAtec0zgbNoCK4OGOAtec0zgbNo";
$iv = "LQjFLCU3sAVplBC3";
$iterations = 1000;
$keyLength = 32;

$prepared_key = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, $keyLength, $iterations, "sha256");

$ciphertext_b64 = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext,"AES-256-CBC", $prepared_key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
echo $ciphertext_b64 . "<br/>";

$plaintext = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($ciphertext_b64),"AES-256-CBC", $prepared_key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
echo $plaintext . "<br/>";
```